Which are heated more by induction heating, magnetically soft or hard materials?
The title says it all. I'm trying to find the best alloy to create heat in a part of an invention.
Thanks.

The amount of heat generated in one AC cycle would be proportional to the area enclosed by the B-H loop of the material.  This information is usually available from manufacturers.  Hard magnetic materials generally have more area enclosed than soft magnetic materials.  So that's the simple answer.
But there is more to consider.  Are you trying to heat the magnet itself or are you trying to create a magnetic field and heat something else with eddy currents?  If you make the magnetic material too hot, it will lose its magnetic properties altogether. There is also the skin effect and frequency to consider. If you just want heat, you may be better off with an electrically resistive element.
